# Show one div which is wrapped with form action, by hovering another div with css

Tags: html, css

I have to "submit" input types (buttons). Actually hamburger bar and one button. I've done responsive design, and need to display div "Anmelden" when I hover on hamburger menu (since it's responsive design). Here is my html and css

```
<nav>
<div id = "hamburger">
    <input type = "submit" value="☰" class ="hamburger">
</div>
<form action ="login.html">
    <div id="abmelden">
        <input type = "submit" value="Abmelden" class = "abmelden">
    </div>
</form>
</nav>
```

and here is CSS for that, which is somehow not working.

```
.hamburger{
font-size: 14px;
color: Gainsboro     ;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102,1), rgba(0, 89, 179,0.8)); 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 9%;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: -35px;
height: 35px;
float: right;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}

#hamburger:hover ~ #abmelden{
display: inline-block;
}


.abmelden{
display: none;
font-size: 14px;
color: Gainsboro     ;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102,1), rgba(0, 89, 179,0.8)); 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 7.5%;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: -35px;
height: 42px;
float: right;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}
```

What went wrong, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#abmelden` is not a sibling of `#hamburger`.

You should use `#hamburger:hover ~ form #abmelden`

`~` is the general sibling selector and only selects elements that are siblings. Siblings are elements that are next to each other **and at the same level in the DOM**. So you have to put `form` and then the child element of form that you want to target (i.e. `#abmelden`).

```css
.hamburger{
font-size: 14px;
color: Gainsboro     ;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102,1), rgba(0, 89, 179,0.8)); 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 9%;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: -35px;
height: 35px;
float: right;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}

#hamburger:hover ~ form #abmelden{
display: inline-block;
}

#abmelden {
display:none;
}

.abmelden{

font-size: 14px;
color: Gainsboro     ;
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102,1), rgba(0, 89, 179,0.8)); 
font-family: sans-serif;
width: 7.5%;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: -35px;
height: 42px;
float: right;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<nav style="margin-top:100px">
<div id = "hamburger">
    <input type = "submit" value="☰" class ="hamburger">
</div>
<form action ="login.html">
    <div id="abmelden">
        <input type = "submit" value="Abmelden" class = "abmelden">
    </div>
</form>
</nav>
```

Comment: @PegasusThorn You are also using the wrong selector for `#abmelden` in your CSS. It should be `#abmelden` not `.abmelden`

Comment: I've changed it now into #abmelden, but somehow nothing is happening when I hover over hamburger, just nothing.

Comment: @PegasusThorn I just realized that you have a div with id "abmelden" and the input with class "abmelden". Your `:hover` CSS was showing the div but the input was still hidden. I moved `display:none` to a new ruleset targeting the ID. Check the snippet in my answer, it is working. It doesn't look very good. I am not sure how you want to style it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the  `form tag` in your div with id `hamburger` and and apply a `hover` with this:

```
#hamburger:hover #abmelden{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Take out `display:none` from `.abmelden` and add it to `#abmelden` because you want the `div` to display as outlined in your requirements

here is a snippet:

```css
.hamburger {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Gainsboro;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102, 1), rgba(0, 89, 179, 0.8));
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 9%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: right;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}

#hamburger:hover #abmelden {
  display: inline-block;
}

#abmelden {
  display: none;
}

.abmelden {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: Gainsboro;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 51, 102, 1), rgba(0, 89, 179, 0.8));
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  height: 42px;
  float: right;
  border: 0px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="hamburger">
    <input type="submit" value="☰" class="hamburger">
    <form action="login.html">
      <div id="abmelden">
        <input type="submit" value="Abmelden" class="abmelden">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```